# Finding a job in UK

Tags: visas, uk

I'm from India and actively looking for technical jobs which give work permit in UK.
Per the UK government site, it should be categorized as `L2` VISA.

I see a few jobs in stackoverflow with tags `VISA SPONSER` and `PAID RELOCATION`.
However, in the jobs posted, I could not figure out what type of VISA will be processed.

**Do I really get a `L2` type VISA which can be converted to `ILR` status after the definite period?**

**At present, I only have a valid `passport`, should I have any other prerequisites before applying for the job?**

Comment: Are you looking/searching properly ? Are you sure L2 is for UK ? `I could not figure out what type of VISA will be processed` Get in touch with the jobs poster to clarify.

Comment: Questions about migration are off topic here but you can try this topic at our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The US has a special visa, L1, for international companies that wish to expand operations into the United States. The L2 is for dependent spouse and unmarried children under 21 years of age of qualified L-1 visa holders.

Comment: My Apologies, I'm referring to UK's Tier 2 VISA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company will most likely want to bring you in for an on-site interview, as an Indian you will need a standard visitor visa for this.

If they decide they want to hire you then they will need to start the process of sponsoring your work visa application. Most likely a "Tier 2 general" visa. IIRC you can't switch from a visitor visa to a Tier 2 in the UK and so you will need to leave the UK after your interview.

AIUI you can remain on Tier 2 general for a total of up to 6 years. After 5 years you can apply for ILR.

Comment: Is it possible to get the visitor VISA in a week's time or should I have the VISA prior applying the job?

Comment: Be aware of scams. Wait for the company to invite you for interview. You will need to submit the letter of invitation as part of your visa application. Companies who can offer a UK Tier 2 visa sponsorship are licenced by the UK government and listed here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers

Comment: Attending the job interview will be the key rationale for your visa application. The standard processing time is 15 days, you can pay for priority processing but there’s no 100% guarantee that you will get a quicker answer. Gathering your supporting documents for an application usually takes a while too.

Comment: @traveller true. But for the asker: the employer will know this takes time so they will plan your interview date to allow for that.